# finite element interpolation formulae

Tags: interpolation

Is there a place where I can found formalas used for interpolation in the Finite Element Method?

I'm look for recipes, where formulas are given for basic 2D and 3D elements, that can just be applied, without any theory.

In other words, there are a lot of ressoures about Finite Element Method theory available on the web, but I'm looking for a site/document that just give the algorithm for interpolation for the most common case, that I can code directly.

I'm especially looking for interpolation formula for P1 Prism (interpolating from the 6 vertices).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're talking about interpolation functions and I guess the formula is the only thing missing in your code, so you can check for them on this [link](https://www.geophysik.uni-muenchen.de/~igel/Lectures/NMG/08_finite_elements_basisfunctions.pdf)  for 1D and 2D.
Now, I don't understand what you mean by "P1 prism". Maybe you should try it with lagrange polynomial. Check Hughes's book "The Finite Element Method" (2000 year edition), page 129, example 4. It might be what you need: an interpolation function for an almost arbitrary dimension  and quantity of nodes.